# function to check a list for n different characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

However, the above does not seem to work either and the code just seems very confusing.

```
while True:
    try:
    name = input("Enter the name of the file:") + ".txt"

    for lines in read: 
        stored.append(lines)
    sqaure(stored)
    checkNChars(stored)

    for content in stored:
        print (content)
```

So the code opens up a file entered by the user and prints the file out and appends it to a list. I then want to use this list to check if the file is a n x n square which the first function does (def square).

However, I also need to check to see if exactly n characters are used and thats where I am confused. I can check for the n x n grid, but not how to see if there is n different characters.

Comment: `checkGrid` returns `True` or `False`, but you're not saving the returned value in your main loop.

Comment: Do you want `n` unique characters in each row, or `n` unique characters total across the grid (so row 0 might have only n - 3 unique characters as long as rows 1-n at some point feature three more unique characters)? `checkGrid` (assuming the indentation was fixed) would require `n` unique characters per row, but wouldn't verify anything about the unique character count for the grid as a whole.

Comment: @ShadowRanger n unique characters total across the grid. So if there is a 3x3 square there must be 3 unique characters , same with 4x4 etc

Comment: If your `checkGrid` function is indented correctly (how you have it in the question) then you need to indent left `return True` because it will return out of the function after the first iteration no matter if it's True or False. Also, could you provide an example of your grid in the question.

Comment: @StevenSummers oh right, so I got the true + flase wrong way round? And added the grid example.

Comment: It's not the wrong way round. It's just indented in 1 too much. Since it will just exit immediately and not iterate through the entire list. Additionally `checkGrid(stored) ` does nothing. You need to assign the returned value and then use that with an if statement to do what you want when you get an invalid grid. (As mentioned by John Gordon)

Comment: @StevenSummers  I'm going to split them into two functions to make it easier for myself to check n x n grid first and then for n unique char.

Comment: If you want. But I think the function you have is sufficient for checking once  you fix the return

Comment: @StevenSummers I did because it makes it easier as I get confused when reading so much lol, not very good at programming but trying to get better. I updated my OP with what I did + asking for a little direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't really need exceptions since each function returns a boolean value. If you do want to do a try / except you can define your own exceptions to use. (Assuming you still want to after Austin's answer)

Answer (score 1):

By way of explanation, your first function, `checkGrid()`, does the following:

1. First, it determines the number of rows in the grid. Since a grid is square, the number of columns must equal the number of rows.
2. For each row, it checks the length of the row (which would be the number of columns in that row). If that does not equal the total number of rows, then this is not a grid.
3. For each row, if the number of columns is correct, it checks the length of a `set()` made up of the elements of that row. Sets, of course, do not contain duplicates. So if the elements are not distinct, then the number of elements in the set will not equal the number of elements in the line (which is equal to the number of rows). If not correct, the row is not made up of distinct elements. (Example: set(A,B,C) = {A,B,C}, but set(A,B,A) = {A,B}.)

The `checkGrid` function, then, does everything you need except for one thing: it doesn't ensure that the elements of the grid are all the same across the rows.

The easiest way to do that would be to modify `checkGrid` to perform the check. Try adding the elements in each row to a single set (over all rows), and then checking the length of the set. If all the rows use the same elements, the set will have the same length as the number of rows:

```
def checkGrid(gd):
    grid = len(gd)
    all_items = set()
    for characters in gd:
        if len(characters) != grid:
            # Not enough columns - not a grid
            return False

        row_items = set(characters)

        if len(row_items) != grid:
            # Not enough items - duplicates
            return False

        all_items |= row_items

    if len(all_items) != grid:
        # Too many items - not reusing the same set for each row
        return False

    # Can't find anything to complain about, so yes.
    return True
```

Comment: Ah interesting, I knew what I was doing wrong with the rows/columns but I had no idea how to actually work around it. Thanks for the explanation also as it helps to learn.  Also in the all_items I= row_items what does the I mean?

Comment: Also as I posted in my OP at the bottom, with the returns I wasn't sure how to put this in my main loop (with error exceptions). Do I  use except: then if statements?

Comment: Sets in python support the `.union()` method, with an operator overload of the `|` (bitwise or) operator. Python also supports the `op=` notation of C, so instead of saying `a = a op b` you can say `a op= b` (for any binary operator `op`). Thus, `|=` is the `op=` form of the bitwise-or operator, which is overloaded for sets to be `.union()`. Which means `all_items |= row_items` is like saying `all_items = all_items.union(row_items)`.

Comment: That said, you should not bother with exceptions. In this case, I'm returning True or False, so just say `if checkGrid(stored): print("It's good!") else: print("It's bad!")` or whatever you need to do.